# Passing a reference of class to another class in scala

Tags: java, scala

I have just a simple question. In scala, I want to call a class reference to another class. But I am not able to figure it out how. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
object Node {
   val E = new Node(NodeType.E)
}
class Node(private var nodeType: NodeType) {
private var nodes: ArrayList[Node] = new ArrayList[Node]()
private var tokens: ArrayList[Token] = new ArrayList[Token]()
// And the remaining method}
```

I have another class named NodeType.scala. Here, I am getting error at NodeType and when the cursor is highlighted it says **not found type NodeType**

Can anyone please explain what the problem is?

Comment: Can't tell without NodeType. Is NodeType a scala enumeration? If so, ensure its implemented like shown in http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.Enumeration including the type and wildcard import.

Comment: But i have both the classes in different file. Is there any way i can call a class from another class file?

Comment: Of course you can use a class from another file. You just need to import it if it's not in the same namespace. More information regarding it would be nice, too..

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know without seeing the definition of NodeType.

From the usage of the Node companion object and how you are accessing the field of the NodeType companion object, I'm wondering whether you forgot to define a class (not an object) for NodeType.

Also, it could technically just be an import issue.